# Synchronizing the components with its schema

Tags: 2011, powertools

I heard about Component synchronizer power tool for 2011, but I don't know whether the tool is active or still in development.

Please let me know is there any alternative way to synchronize Components? We are using Tridion 2011 Sp1 version

If the tool is ready then please provide the link to download.

Comment: Tridion 2013 SP1 (finally) added an API call to help with that. See here: http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/12/tridion-2013-sp1-synchronizing.html. But since you're on Tridion 2011 SP1, this is of no use to you. I just put it here for completeness and later visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Porter to achieve Component Synchronization. See blog post here:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tag/content-porter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [Component Synchronizer](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/ComponentSynchronizer) is still in development. However you can easily do this using the [Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/333/alternative-to-component-synchronizer).

Comment: but thats in 2013 SP1 not in 2011

Comment: Good point! I've removed that from my answer!