# Coreservice Component XML / Schema Sync function?

Tags: core-service, xml, schema-synchronization

When opening components in the CME, should the XML not match with the Schema XSD, the GUI will throw out any nodes that are no longer part of the XSD, and (typically) allow this to save.

I'm wondering if there's a core service function to perform this operation or if that's something that needs to be written?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the function is available if you are on Tridion 2013 or later version of Tridion. The function is SynchronizeWithSchemaAndUpdate.

There is one nice article by Eric for using this functionality from core service: [Synchronize components](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/12/tridion-2013-sp1-synchronizing.html)

If you are using 2011 then there should be power tools for it, details are given here: [Synchronize Component in version older than 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/synchronizing-the-components-with-its-schema)